# Толерантность и терпимость

Tags: синонимы

Сегодня слово "толерантность" несет негативный оттенок (и тут я прекрасно понимаю, почему). Но хотелось бы разобраться с равнозначностью слов "толерантность" (не в медицинском значении, где это означает степень принятия организмов чужеродной ткани) и "терпимость". Почему-то в отношении всевозможных пороков все чаще сейчас звучит именно слово "толерантность", и почему никогда - "терпимость".
Хотелось бы узнать, что вы думаете насчет этих слов?

Comment: >"толерантность" (не в медицинском значении, где это означает степень принятия организмов чужеродной ткани)

И еще толерантность -- это способность организма привыкать к какой-либо химии: наркотикам, алкоголю (где этиловый спирт, как наркотик), лекарствам. Часто сопровождается сильным желанием принять соответствующий препарат, поэтому такое привыкание может быть опасно для здоровья.

Когда-то немного разбирался с этой темой, поэтому могу здесь не короткий комментарий, а целый доклад написать :-)

Comment: Ну да, это вообще способность организма принимать что-то в себя и не отторгать.

Answer (score 3):

ТЕРПИМОСТЬ

Мы говорим: неприятный, но терпимый  – соответственно,  слово «терпимый»  изначально несет несколько негативный оттенок значения. Терпимость – это поведенческая норма,  которая предполагает  непротестное отношение к явлениям, которые неприятны. Причины могут быть разные:  я не могу это исправить, общество не может это исправить,  такова природа человека (о домах терпимости).

Впоследствии значение слова было расширено, ему стали придавать ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНЫЙ СМЫСЛ  – терпимое отношение не к недостаткам, а к тому, что тебе несвойственно,  понимание того, что тебе несвойственно, в том числе поведение, мнение, а также   религиозная и национальная терпимость, например: «Их труд и востребован там, где необходимо милосердие, терпимость, доброта, любовь».  «Заранее попрошу всех комментаторов проявлять вежливость и терпимость».

Таким образом, слово «терпимость»  имеет разные оттенки значений:  с одной стороны, это   отсутствие протеста, снисходительность, с другой -  понимание по отношению к  несвойственному.

ТОЛЕРАНТНОСТЬ

Слово «толерантность»  не связано со значением «терпеть неприятное» ― оно в большей степени обозначает именно понимание, а не терпение: «ты не лучше другого, а он ― не выше тебя». Также под толерантностью не подразумевается уступка, снисхождение, и это не отказ от своего мнения.

С другой стороны,  толерантность обычно приписывается европейской цивилизации, и не все считают это качество положительным, например:  «Толерантность ― извращенная терпимость». «Толерантность – это победа псевдоморали над здравым смыслом». «Хваленая европейская толерантность, похоже, трещит по швам».  «Это то, что на Западе называют безликим словом «толерантность».

ОБЛАСТЬ ПРИМЕНЕНИЯ

В настоящее  время  эти слова взаимозаменяемы, но, возможно, различаются по стилю и области применения: «толерантность»  в большей степени используется в политике, а  «терпимость»  ― по отношению к частным явлениям жизни, например: «Толерантность ― модное сегодня слово российского политического и научного лексикона».
«Терпимость к ранним сексуальным связям у нас стала гораздо выше, чем раньше».
А вот пример иронического использования слова при смешении стилей: «Попробуйте сохранить европейскую толерантность при развитии московского скандала».

Answer (score 1):

Слово пришло из английского, где оно звучит как tolerance.
Чтобы подчеркнуть, что это общественно-политический термин, язык предпочитает иностранное слово. Ведь толерантность отличается же от обычной терпимости? В длинных очередях или в автомобильных пробках мы что должны проявлять – толерантность или все же терпимость?

Answer (score 0):

Отношение к слову "толерантность" определяется отношением к "источнику заимствования". Думаю, не так сложно найти человека, который "не заметит" негативного оттенка, появившегося у данного слова. А в ответ на предложение использовать слово "терпимость" - обвинит Вас в мракобесии.
Что же касается использования.. Так уж получилось, что терпимость сейчас "не в моде". Ни у сторонников слова "толерантность", ни у его противников.